# python while True loop ends eventually and silently, how to keep it running?

Tags: python, linux, bash, loops

I have a

```
while True:
   poll_some_data_from_a_server_and_save_it_to_a_file()
   time.sleep(5)
```

loop. It runs great for a while, but eventually simply stops without an error. I run it on AWS with

```
python file.py > logfile &
```

And there is no hint in the logfile on what happened, the python process is simply missing in htop after a certain time. How can I go about debugging what happens and keep it running longer?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stderr as well?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Given that he asks "how can I go about debugging", what you posted is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try nohup which runs the process in background:

```
nohup python file.py > logfile &
```

The output will be logged in the file named `nohup.out`

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it out right now and will report back how it works. Trying to understand bash redirects, is it similar to &> or 2>       ?

Answer (score -2):

You could create an infinite loop like:

```
While 1:
    try:
        data = poll_some_data_from_a_server_and_save_it_to_a_file()
        with open("FileName.txt", "a") as f:
        for n in data:
            f.write(n + "\n")
        f.close()
    except IOError as e:
        print e
```

It will try write each item it finds in poll to file if a problem occurs it will be captured and printed to screen.

Comment: This isn't correct syntax, and `while 1 == True` is not Pythonic in the least.

Comment: @nneonneo Although it may not be "pythonic" the syntax is correct it doesnt throw an error in interactive python. I have amended it. Is this better?

Comment: I can see the idea behind it, but I'm not sure it is an IOError, is there a way to capture any error and print it?